# Express + Passport.js: req.user is UNDEFINED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, passport.js

I've got an express API server and separately a create-react-app app with no proxy. I use passport.js for OAuth, that looks in MongoDB to deserialize user.

In the backend, I setup cors middleware and in the frontend, I configured axios base URL with my server URL.

With postman/manually writing endpoint in the URL bar, my API request succeed and req.user was found. But if I make that API request from the frontend with axios, req.user is undefined or an empty string.

I can't figure out, please help me, guys.

middlewares.js

```
  app.use(cors())

  app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  }))

  app.use(compression())

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    app.use(morgan('tiny'))
  }

  app.use(bodyParser.json())

  app.use(helmet())

  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())
```

authRoutes.js

```
  app.get(
    '/auth/current_user',
    (req, res) => {
      res.send(req.user)
      console.log(req.user) // UNDEFINED ONLY WITH AXIOS IN REACT APP
    }
  )
```

actions.js

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL

export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/auth/current_user')
  console.log('USER DATA: ')
  console.log(data === '') // TRUE
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: data
  })
}
```

passport-config.js

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user)
  })
})
```

steps to reproduce:

- clone server https://github.com/darioielardi/triplan-server
- clone client https://github.com/darioielardi/triplan-client
- on server: npm run start-dev
- on client: npm start

when you login with google, auth flow goes right but ( as you can see in "network" chrome devtools tab ) the '/auth/current_user' api request has response.data === ""

Comment: so how are you sending the user using axios? in your code it depends on the request, and your axios does not send any, so how are you expecting the user to be there?

Comment: I don't want to send the user, I want to GET the user. With passport the user should be in req.user, so with axios I want to fetch user data in my react app.

Comment: which does not makes sense you know what im saying? just look at your code. your not sending any auth headers.

Comment: question updated with passport config

Comment: so when this block ```const { data } = await axios.get('/auth/current_user')``` is run are you already logged in?

Comment: I use that fetchUser redux-thunk to get user data, or undefined if the user is not logged in. When the user is logged in, I can get data with writing in my url bar 'localhost:5000/auth/current_user', but not in my react app with axios in that redux-thunk.

Comment: can you check if axios has error? using try catch

Comment: using try catch axios has not any error. what do you think about?

Comment: async/await in redux-thunk absolutely works, I got other project with async/await in redux-thunk and everything works.

Comment: yea just saw it. so try ```const req = await axios...``` instead of the data and see what the response is

Comment: thanks for suggestion, response object have data property === "", and the request status is 200 OK

Comment: so that means its really empty. can you produce a repo so i can check everything else. i feel this is a problem regarding your backend

Comment: also are you sure you are calling the right endpoint? what is this ```process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL```

Comment: steps to reproduce added, thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: cant test it sorry, so many sensitive informations needed. good luck debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i`ve got a solution.

**Backend**

First of all you must install cors `npm install --save cors`, than paste this code.

```
import cors from 'cors'

app.use(cors({
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true 
}))
```

**Frontend**

Use axios with credentials and headers options:

```
const config = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/routes/register', user, config);
```

I hope it will help you or someone else.