# axios.get not returning data

Tags: node.js, express, axios, passport.js

I'm using react, express and passport to manage the auth flow.

I recently separated the frontend and the backend into two apps in Heroku, and I'm trying to connect both sides (before I had the a client folder inside the server folder). When testing locally, my backend works after login accessing to http://localhost:5000/auth/current_user, but when I use axios and call from my redux action it doesn't return any response.

This is my code from the front side:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/auth/current_user"
    );
    console.log("fetchUser: ", res);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response) {
      console.log("fetchUser:", e.response);
    }
  }
};
```

When I log my backend side to see if there's a session, I get `{}` as response. Sometimes, randomly I do get the passport info `{ passport: { user: '5da9b04eb086af53103ec4e9' } }`

```
  app.get("/auth/current_user", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send(req.user);
  });
```

Headers from Chrome are the following (without any response...):
[Chrome headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aENmV.png)

Would be great if someone can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: res is coming or not.

Comment: where should I look at? if I log res on the backend I do get a huge response (sorry, I'm quite new in this...)

Comment: In passport, I tried to log every step (serializeUser, deserializeUser, ...) and data is returned.
`passport.use(
  new OAuth2CognitoStrategy(
  options,
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    // console.log(profile);
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ cognitoId: profile.sub });
     // console.log("existingUser: ", existingUser);
     if (existingUser) {
       return done(null, existingUser);
     }
     const user = await new User({
       cognitoId: profile.sub,
       email: profile.email
     }).save();
     done(null, user);
   }
 )`

Comment: check via console.log(res.data)

Comment: Oh, ok. No, there is no data.
I've been trying to see where the information is lost. When logging req at my callback function, I see references to the session ` session: { user: '5da9b04eb086af53103ec4e9' } }` and to req.user.
Could it be because of different domains/subdomans? api.example.com vs. www.example.com? In any case, I'm trying on localhost and only port changes. I'm using cors on the back.

Comment: Passport is worki ?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem. Posted it below. It was a CORS problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to the problem... Seems like it was a CORS problem. I don't really understand it clearly, but will study it.

So, partially, the solution was in this answer: [Express + Passport.js: req.user is UNDEFINED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501485/express-passport-js-req-user-is-undefined)

With this, the cookies appeared in my console log at the front side. To fully work, I had to add the origin domain to the cors.

In conclusion, I added to my index.js at the server side:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
);
```

And this config to my axios get:

```
    const config = {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this, you can use cors npm like this.

```
npm install --save cors

var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
/* your regular routes go here */
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using cors, but also I had to add the credentials setting. Thanks!